# Get places in a given geographical area (code optimization)

Tags: python, dataframe, optimization, haversine

I have a DataFrame with latitude and longitude of places (`restaurants`) and a DataFrame with latitude and longitude of neighborhoods (`area`).

I would like, for each neighborhood, to count the number of restaurants in a 3km area (`numberR`).

I have written the following code, and it works:

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
numberR=[]
radius=3

for element in range(0,area['lon'].count()): #for every neighborhood  
    df=pd.DataFrame()
    df['destLat']=restaurants['lat']
    df['originLat']=areas['lat'][element]
    df['destLon']= restaurants['lng']
    df['originLon']=area['lon'][element]

    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        #for every restaurant I compute the distance from my neighborhood in km
        l=[haversine(df.originLon[i],df.originLat[i],df.destLon[i],df.destLat[i]) for i, row in df.iterrows()]

    numberR.append(sum(x<radius for x in l))
```

However, I would like to make the code quicker as it is very slow.

Do you have any idea on how could I do to reach the same result in less time?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. `haversine` is the well known function for getting distance in km starting from lat and lng.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use functions from [scipy.spacial.distance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html).

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

distances = cdist(areas, restaurants, metric=haversine)  # metric accepts a callable
sum(distances > 3)  # sums columns
```

The `cdist` function computes distances between each pair of rows of the two DataFrames.

Also, you should modify the haversine function as to be able to accept DataFrame rows.